# 'Were' or 'are' in the conditional tense?

Tags: conditionals

I am not sure how a sentence I want to write should be written:

> 1. I would choose the apple in the case where an unknown number of apples **were** to be stored in the box.
> 2. I would choose the apple in the case where an unknown number of apples **are** to be stored in the box.

Should I write *were* or *are*, please?

I am new to this forum, so I apologise if this question has been asked before.
Furthermore, I apologise if I have not correctly worded my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First sentence is correct because it is Second Conditional with construction of *if + were to + plain form + would + present infinitive* such as in the sentence

> *If we were to answer that question, I don't know what we would say.*